# accessing structures using dynamic arrays for indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing, structure

To compute the overall mass of a 2D structural system, I have obtained information about the area, the properties (stored in "props"-structure array) and material (stored in "mats"-structure array) of each structural component.

I can loop over the total number of elements and compute the mass individually by area * thickness * density but would like to do this without having to use a for-loop.

```
% This is the database
area = [100 300 500];

props.shell(1).thic = 5;
props.shell(2).thic = 10;

mats.alu(1).rho   = 10;
mats.alu(2).rho   = 15;
mats.steel(1).rho = 20;
mats.steel(2).rho = 25;
```

For example, if I want to compute the mass of elements 1 and 3, the following look-up tables are determined:

```
% beforehand computed field names and indices
a_idx  = [1 3] 

p_name = {'shell' 'shell'};
p_idx  = [1 2];

m_name = {'alu' 'steel'};
m_idx  = [2 1];

% this works
mass = 0;
for i = 1 : numel(a_idx)
    mass = mass + area(a_idx(i)) * props.(p_name{i})(p_idx(i)).thic * mats.(m_name{i})(m_idx(i)).rho
end
```

This is how I would like it to work :)

```
mass = sum(area(a_idx) .* [props.(p_name)(p_idx).thic] .* [mats.(m_name)(m_idx).rho])
```

I already tried

```
mass = sum(area(a_idx) .* [props.(p_name{:})(p_idx).thic] .* [mats.(m_name{:})(m_idx).rho])
```

but sadly I cannot get the indexing with the string right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're trying to use [dynamic field references](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) with a cell array of field names is the sticking point here. There's really no good shorthand notation to do it. The only option I can think of is to convert the top-level structure array into a cell array using [`struct2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html), but this creates a much more complicated looking approach, all to avoid a for loop that is quite simple and, honestly, probably more efficient.

If you're curious, here's what avoiding a for loop would look like:

```
% Get thickness:
propData = struct2cell(props);
[~, index] = ismember(p_name, fieldnames(props));
propData = vertcat(propData{index});
thickness = [propData(sub2ind(size(propData), 1:numel(p_name), p_idx)).thic];

% Get density:
matData = struct2cell(mats);
[~, index] = ismember(m_name, fieldnames(mats));
matData = vertcat(matData{index});
density = [matData(sub2ind(size(matData), 1:numel(m_name), m_idx)).rho];

% Calculate mass:
mass = sum(area(a_idx).*thickness.*density);
```

Comment: “probably more efficient“. Yeah, copying all that data just to avoid a loop... That’s so last decade. :)

Comment: Thank you very much @gnovice! I was curious if there is an elegant matrix-ish way since you get indoctrinated all the time, that loops are bad and slow and as the name Matlab says, it's optimized for matrix operations :)